# Make CKEditor Toolbox open by-default

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor version 3.6.6 and I want to make the toolbox open by-default in editor. Currently it comes close and you need to click on the toolbox icon to open this. Is there any way to make this open by-default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in CKEditor config file (`ckeditor.config.js`).
We need to set the following flag to `true`:

```
toolbarStartupExpanded : false
```